# Parsing JSON - print works, but append doesn't

Tags: python, json

I have a file with a bunch of JSON objects. I try to parse through object by object, trying to get the `id_str` only. When I print, it works (one id_str per line). But, when I try to append it to a list, it gives me a KeyError id_str. So I'm not sure why it works when printing but not when appending.

```
import zipfile
id_list = []
with open("sample.json", "r") as zip:
  for i in zip:
    jobj = json.loads(i)
    print(jobj["id_str"]) # this prints each id (works)
    id_list.append(jobj["id_str"]) # same as above, but appends to list (KeyError id_str)
```

Sample of file with JSON objects:

```
{
    "truncated": false,
    "contributors": null,
    "reply_count": 0,
    "retweeted": false,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "source": "<a href=\"omitted_link" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for Android</a>",
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "id": 1234272705391874048,
    "retweet_count": 0,
    "filter_level": "low",
    "id_str": "1234272705391874048",
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "lang": "tr",
    "favorited": false,
    "favorite_count": 0,
    "coordinates": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "created_at": "Mon Mar 02 00:21:59 +0000 2020",
    "timestamp_ms": "1583108519300",
    "text": "\u00d6yle sevdim ki seni beni g\u00f6ren herkes yerinde olmak istedi.",
    "quote_count": 0,
    "geo": null,
    "is_quote_status": false
} 
{
    "truncated": true,
    "contributors": null,
    "reply_count": 0,
    "retweeted": false,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "source": "<a href=\"omitted_link" rel=\"nofollow\">pywws</a>",
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "id": 1234268093091926016,
    "retweet_count": 0,
    "filter_level": "low",
    "id_str": "1234268093091926016",
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "lang": "en",
    "favorited": false,
    "favorite_count": 0,
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "created_at": "Mon Mar 02 00:03:39 +0000 2020",
    "timestamp_ms": "1583107419642",
    "text": "Sunday 01 March 2020\n23:58 GMT\nTemperature: 1.6\u00b0C\nWind: S, 0 mph (ave), 5 mph (gust)\nHumidity: 95%\nRain (today): 0.\u2026 omitted_link",
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "quote_count": 0,
    "geo": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [52.417, -1.442]
    },
    "is_quote_status": false
}
```

Comment: Are you sure *every* file has a top-level object with that key?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. If the print statement works, the append statement should work as well. Are you saying that you get no errors if you comment out the append statement?

Comment: i tried running your code with the data zipped as a txt in a zip file and it's throwing an error: `TypeError: 'ZipFile' object is not iterable`, please provide a more detailed example that works

Comment: @JaredSmith It's a big file with thousands of objects, so I can't be 100% certain. But, I'm it should. Worse case is that there's still that key, but it's value is empty. Also, I'm only opening 1 file for now.

Comment: @JussiNurminen I've let the print version run for a pretty long while, and no errors thus far. The append version throws a KeyError within a couple of seconds. So ye, comment out append statement and print works as I expected to.

Comment: @Knovolt The reason is probably that `print()` slows it down, so you don't see the error. But eventually it will error out, because the `print()` is accessing the exact same key. The real reason for the error is that one of your JSON objects doesn't have the key `id_str`. You have to either fix the input data or modify your code to deal with that problem.

Comment: Just put the property access in a try/execpt KeyError block and print the offending object, you'll see it. Or use `.get` instead of square brackets. This is all basic python coding stuff.

Comment: @vencaslac Apologies, I've now changed it to just open/read the file without zip format.

Comment: @JussiNurminen and JaredSmith thanks! I tried to catch the objects causing the problem, and it turns our there were half a dozen objects without that key. The print statement was indeed slowing it down making it seem like there were no errors.

Comment: @Knovolt glad you got it fixed

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Knovolt i did what you are doing here using re module and tested on your sample and it worked so test this

```
import re

with open ('sample.json','r') as reader :
    Readed = reader.readlines()

for item in Readed :
    if re.findall('"id_str"',item) :
        with open ('IDS_YOU_WANTED.txt','a') as writer :
            writer.write(item)
```